# Refactoring random number generation

Tags: ruby

As I'm learning Ruby I wrote this little program to generate a "nice" number randomly (like 4747, 6969, etc.).
As I'm currently breaking the "do not repeat yourself" rule, how would you refactor the following?

```
def nice_numbers
    a = rand(9)
    b = rand(9)
    c = rand(9)
    d = rand(9)
    while a != c || b != d
        a = rand(9)
        b = rand(9)
        c = rand(9)
        d = rand(9)
    end
    nice = [a,b,c,d].join
end

puts nice_numbers
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you are generating `c` and `d` at all - what is the purpose if you always want  `a == c` and `b == d`? It would save you almost all your code if you just did `[a,b,a,b].join` at the end rather than force a "random" number to match. In fact it's a one liner `([rand(9),rand(9)]*2).join`

Comment: You are right, Neil, so much simpler! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code:

```
def nice_numbers
  ([rand(9),rand(9)]*2).join
end
```

generates the same output as your function. It is also faster, as it does not test then regenerate anything.

If you want to DRY this up for `rand(9)`:

```
def nice_numbers
  (Array.new(2) {rand(9)} * 2).join
end
```

Ruby language features used in this last example:

- Array constructor takes a size param and a block to fill the Array
- Multiplying an array by an integer repeats the array

Comment: You don't even need an array: `'%02d' % rand(99) * 2`

Comment: @Stefan: Nice alternative idea. Doesn't output same as OP's code though, because the digits can take value `9` (but you would never see `99`). Probably `rand(100)` would work for OP though, and `rand(10)` - or even `rand(9)+1` - would be suitable in this answer.

Comment: Good catch, I thought it would be `0 <= rand(n) <= n`